# Meaning of ‘Pia hat heute früher aus’

Tags: meaning, translation

> Pia hat heute früher aus

What does this sentence mean? I’m learning German and translation softwares couldn’t give me meaningful results.

Comment: Are there any parts that you can already identify? Are there any specific words that are causing you trouble? We are not a translation service for entire sentences.

Answer (score 5):

E.g. if you are at work or at school you could say:

> Ich habe heute früher aus.

This means your working hours/school day/classes **end earlier as usual/ as expected/ compared to X**.

So in your example:

> "Pia's (school day) is over earlier today"

Without a comparison it is a short form. Often used in context of school or work, to indicate a deviation from the expected working hours or length of the school day.
But you can extend this to use it as an comparison e.g.:

> Pia hat heute früher aus, als ihr Bruder / als normalerweise.

Comment: +1 but it doesn't have to mean that it ends earlier *than usual*, it could also mean earlier than yesterday, earlier than her brother, and so on.

Comment: Thanks, yes you are right. I added "as expected" and some additional information.

Answer (score 2):

The sentence consists of four components:

> Pia

a girls name, subject of the sentence,

two adverbs,

> früher

'earlier' and

> heute

'today', and the verb 'aushaben' in the 3rd person singular:

> hat ... aus.

---

According to the [Duden](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/aushaben) 'aushaben' has four meanings. In this sentence only one makes sense:

> Schulschluss haben.

---

Putting the pieces back together you get:

> Pia is out of school earlier today.